# Extract unique list of values in one column based on list of values in another column

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Basically, I've extracted a list of software applications running on all of our assets including servers, notebooks and desktops. For each asset in column A, column B shows a list of every application running on it. The entire table of just those two columns is 200,000 rows long.

I have a third column C that only lists 600 server asset names, which is a subset of the 8,000 assets in column A. I'd like to generate a list of unique pieces of software from column B running only on servers in column A.

I realize this can be accomplished with a filter which would be very time-consuming. I'm wondering if anyone can figure out an Excel formula to solve this.

Comment: Running an array formula on 200K rows of data will take longer than filtering. Use a database.

Answer (score 0):

You might insert a column between A and B with a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D:D,1,0)
```

copied down to suit, pivot Columns B and C (C under B and both in ROWS, Tabular Form and with Repeat item labels) then filter the PT to exclude `#N/A` and apply Sort & Filter, Advanced to select the applications with Copy to: somewhere suitable and Unique records only checked.